# Passing a dynamic input box value to a an autocomplete get URL

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, get

I am using jQuery autocomplete tempplate that I found many years ago on the web. In a new autocomplete applicaton, I need to add a dynamic variable in the URL get string. This dynamic variable originates from another input box.The URL parameter $(database_name) below does not get loaded dynamically. It seems to get loaded when the page is loaded in at start.

Is there a way to do this without creating a trigger to reload the autocomplete.js file?
Code follows ...

var database_name="#database_name"; //html id
$("input#cities").autocomplete( {source:"../../../cgi-bin/rfdb/auto_suggest.pl?table_name=world&search_key=city&database="+ $(database_name).val(),
                minLength:0,
                delay:1,
                enable:true,
                cacheLength:1,
                close:function(event,ui){}
                });

Answer (score 0):

I used an autocomplete POST. It seems that "Get" does not dynamically update the variable name. POST does.